# Convert raster outputs to data.frame format

Tags: raster, r

I've moved over to version 2 of the lidR package. In previous versions, the output of `grid_metrics` was a `data.frame`. In version 2.0, the outputs are stored in `raster` format. I have additional code, such as running a PCA that works with the metrics in a `data.frame`.

Is there a suggested method for converting the `raster` products back into a `data.frame`?

Comment: `rasterToPoints` will convert a raster to a 3-column x,y,value matrix. Is that what you want? Or `raster::as.data.frame(r,xy=TRUE)` if you want a data frame.

Comment: 'raster::as.data.frame(r,xy=TRUE)'  works, specifically, with the 'xy = TRUE' option.  The output data frame names the various 'stdmetrics' as layer.1, layer.2 etc. Without renaming the columns using a list containing the metrics names, is there a way to preserve the proper field names?

Comment: If `r` is a stack of raster layers then the column names are the names of the raster layers. If your `stdmetrics` is a stack and doesn't have the names you want, you probably need to name it.

Answer (score 5):

Make a sample raster:

```
> r1 = raster(matrix(1:12,3,4))
```

make two more and make a stack with names:

```
> r2 = r1 + 1
> r3 = r1 + 2
> s = stack(list(r1=r1, r2=r2, r3=r3))
> names(s)
[1] "r1" "r2" "r3"
```

Now convert to data frame:

```
> as.data.frame(s, xy=TRUE)
       x         y r1 r2 r3
1  0.125 0.8333333  1  2  3
2  0.375 0.8333333  4  5  6
3  0.625 0.8333333  7  8  9
4  0.875 0.8333333 10 11 12
5  0.125 0.5000000  2  3  4
6  0.375 0.5000000  5  6  7
7  0.625 0.5000000  8  9 10
8  0.875 0.5000000 11 12 13
9  0.125 0.1666667  3  4  5
10 0.375 0.1666667  6  7  8
11 0.625 0.1666667  9 10 11
12 0.875 0.1666667 12 13 14
>
```

Note that `rasterToPoints` does a similar thing, but returns a matrix:

```
> rasterToPoints(s)
          x         y r1 r2 r3
 [1,] 0.125 0.8333333  1  2  3
 [2,] 0.375 0.8333333  4  5  6
 [3,] 0.625 0.8333333  7  8  9
```

*but* if all values are NA that point is omitted from the output. `as.data.frame` preserves all points:

Make first pixel NA in all layers:

```
> s[[1]][1,1]=NA;s[[2]][1,1]=NA;s[[3]][1,1]=NA
```

Then:

```
> head(rasterToPoints(s))
         x         y r1 r2 r3
[1,] 0.375 0.8333333  4  5  6
[2,] 0.625 0.8333333  7  8  9
[3,] 0.875 0.8333333 10 11 12
[4,] 0.125 0.5000000  2  3  4
[5,] 0.375 0.5000000  5  6  7
[6,] 0.625 0.5000000  8  9 10
```

compare:

```
> head(as.data.frame(s,xy=TRUE))
      x         y r1 r2 r3
1 0.125 0.8333333 NA NA NA
2 0.375 0.8333333  4  5  6
3 0.625 0.8333333  7  8  9
4 0.875 0.8333333 10 11 12
5 0.125 0.5000000  2  3  4
6 0.375 0.5000000  5  6  7
```